# Can't Create Txt file with xamarin.forms c# in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I'm trying to create a txt file for every new day using standard c#. I don't know if I need permission from the OS or something. I set you breakpoints it the code goes as if it did create the txt file but when I check the storage in the device it's nowhere to be found. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TacosSales.Helpers
{
    public class RegisterSale
    {
        public void DailySale(int sale, int sodas, int tacos)
        {
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documents, $"ventas_{DateTime.Today.ToString("yy-MMM-dd")}.txt");
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(filename, $"{time}\n--------------\nVenta: {sale}\nTacos: {tacos}\nSodas: {sodas}\n");

            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(myFile, true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine($"{time}: {sale}\nTacos: {tacos}\nSodas: {sodas}\n");
                }
            }

        }
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?  Are you getting an error or exception?  Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: On Android, `MyDocuments` is mapped to `/files`, so did you check there and didn't find the file?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Isolated Storage. It is a library that puts a layer over all the platforms and will store data in the device's local storage in an isolated way so that only your app can access it.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/

It's similar to using normal C# file access but you don't have to worry about the device's full path as that's not relevant to you unless you need to expose the file to other applications.